# Можно ли как-то у инициализированного родителя перехватить поле?

Tags: java, объекты

В программе при открытии окна инициализируются объекты: родитель и его наследники.
У родителя во время инициализации заполняется некое поле, которое нужно для работы наследников.

1. Можно ли вообще перехватить поле, если вроде как объекты то уже инициализировались?
2. Как можно решить данную проблему? (П.с. думаю будут варианты с "вывести блок кода в метод" - да, я пытался так сделать, но сходу не получается(чужой класс)).

Comment: наследник может переопределить метод инициализации у родителя

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, т.е. я могу сделать чтобы сначала грузились наоборот ? Но по иерархии загрузки так же не произойдет - создается перент -> а потом уже наследник.

Или касательно , что я могу переопределить методы инициализации в дочерних?

Comment: П.С. поле к которому я обращаюсь можно сделать Static - тогда оно и обновляется динамически везде - из-за этого и сразу работает.

Но такой вариант мне кажется сумасшедшим, при геттерах - передает начальное (не инициализированное ) значение.

Comment: Наследники имеют доступ к полям (и всему остальному), объявленным protected и выше, не очень понятна задача

Comment: @Maxim - смотри, родитель и наследник инициализируются одновременно. Т.е. при инциализации наследника, я не могу захватить поля родителя(созданного объекта), т.к. это происходит одновременно. (По логам видел что сначала появляются объекты, а потом заполняется нужное мне поле).

Собственно вопрос как без статика решить это красиво.

Comment: Переопределяйте нужную логику в классах-наследниках (то, что вы называете "дочерними"). Переопределить можно в конструкторе наследника или переопределить сами методы у наследника. В чем проблема то?